# How combine Firebase Realtime Database callbacks with RxJava2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-java2

My current Android project has its different types of reference data held in a Firebase Realtime Database.

The Android application holds its own local copy of this reference data which must be refreshed based on a Last Updated Date.

I wish to use RxJava to control the refresh this reference data in parallel.

Once all the reference data has been refreshed successfully I wish to reset the Last Updated Date locally to todays date.

The solution I have currently does not behave as desired. I cannot get the Last Updated Date reset to wait for the successful refresh of the reference data.

My code currently resembles this:-

```
    Observable.just(Boolean.TRUE)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(refresh -> referenceTypeA())
            .doOnNext(refresh -> referenceTypeB())
            .doOnNext(refresh -> referenceTypeC())
            .doOnNext(refresh -> recordTodaysDate())
            .subscribe();
```

Each of the `referenceTypeX()` methods have the same structure as follows:-

```
private void referenceTypeX() {

        firebaseService
                .getReferenceTypeX()
                .doAfterSuccess(this::referenceTypeX)
                .doOnError(this::processError)
                .subscribe();
    }


public Single<List<ReferenceTypeX>> getReferenceTypeX() {
    return Single.create(emitter ->
            mReferenceTypeXDatabaseReference
                    .orderByChild("typeXKey")
                    .addValueEventListener(buildTypeXListener(emitter)));
}
```

this is where the issue is, as the Firebase callback runs on the main thread and some of the reference data has 1000's of rows I process the data change event on a background thread as follows:-

```
public class TypeXListener extends BaseValueEventListener<List<ReferenceTypeX>> {
    private static final TypeXMapper TYPE_X_MAPPER = Selma.builder(TypeXMapper.class).build();
    private static final List<ReferenceTypeX> TYPE_X = new ArrayList<>();

    public TypeXListener(final SingleEmitter<List<ReferenceTypeX>> emitter) {
        super(emitter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final GenericTypeIndicator<TypeXCsv> typeXTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<TypeXCsv>() {
        };

        final Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            for (final DataSnapshot typeXDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final TypeXCsv typeXCsv = typeXDataSnapshot.getValue(typeXDataSnapshot);
                final TypeX typeX = TypeXMapper.mapTypeX(typeXCsv);

                TYPE_X_s.add(typeX);
            }

            emitter.onSuccess(TYPE_X_s);
        });

        thread.start();

    }
}
```

I believe I need to create an Observable for each of the `referenceTypeX()` methods and pass them to my `Observable.just()`

then use flatMap() to parallelise the reference data updates.

How do I achieve this?

Especially when I need the firebase realtime callback to run on a background thread and not on the main thread?

I believe my solution will resemble something like

```
Observable.just(referenceTypeA(), referenceTypeB(), referenceTypeC())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(?????????????)
                .doOnComplete(recordTodaysDate())
                .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `referenceTypeX()` functions so they do not subscribe in the function:

```
private Single<List<ReferenceTypeX>> referenceTypeX() {
    return firebaseService
            .getReferenceTypeX()
            .doAfterSuccess(this::referenceTypeX)
            .doOnError(this::processError)
            .subscribe(); // <-- remove this, just return
}
```

Then you can build the main observable by combining these functions:

```
Single
    .zip(
        referenceTypeA().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        referenceTypeB().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        referenceTypeC().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
        Function3<A,B,C,Result> { combineIntoResult(...) })
    .flatMap(???) // is this necessary?
    .map(recordTodaysDate())
    .subscribe();
```